# Connect mysql database on host from wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, remote-access

I want to connect my hosts mysql from my wamp host. 
I tried  this;

I've done "%" and ip adress thing on cpanel/remote access

```
$dbhost ="xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:3306";
$dbuser ="user";
$dbpass ="password";
$dbname ="databasename"; 
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
```

but it's not working.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Can you clarify what 'my host' is? Most hosting companies will not allow you to connect to their MySQL servers from outside their network. As a side note as of PHP 5.5 the mysql_* functions have bee deprecated, you might want to look into PDO.

Comment: mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die(mysql_error());- u can see the error in it.

Comment: `it's not working` is pretty vague. You should use also `mysqli_` functions instead of `mysql_` functions because they are depracted

Answer (score 0):

it should work except if one of the parameter is false , so if it's just in localhost try without number of port ?